# How does spacy split "'s"?

Tags: tokenize, spacy

Spacy gives name's as 2 tokens -> name, 's. How could I combine those two tokens? Which rule define the splitting of "'s", infix, or others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For spacy v2.2.3+, you can use [`nlp.tokenizer.explain()`](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#tokenizer-debug) to see which tokenizer settings lead to particular tokens:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")

nlp.tokenizer.explain("name's")
# [('TOKEN', 'name'), ('SUFFIX', "'s")]
```

For English, variants of `'s` are matched by the `suffix_search` setting. You can modify the suffix regex in order to modify this for the tokenizer: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions